# Why do i get an empty String from jquery find().text()?

Tags: jquery

This snipped is multiple times in my code, and i want to get user_id from the selected user

```
<li>
    <div class="contact">
        <div class="contact-name">James</div>
        <p class="user_id">1234</p>
        <div class="remove" onclick="remove()">Remove</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The code for jquery gets me an empty alert. I dont know what to change to get the user_id.

```
    function remove() {
        var id = $(this).parent().find('.user_id').text();
        alert(id)
        ....
```

Does someone has an idea what i have to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onclick="remove()"
```

You should pass *this* into your function to reference the clicked element. By using *this* in your function, you are referencing to *window* scope.

```js
function remove(clickedEl) {
  var id = $(clickedEl).parent().find('.user_id').text();
  console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    <div class="contact">
        <div class="contact-name">James</div>
        <p class="user_id">1234</p>
        <div class="remove" onclick="remove(this)">Remove</div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked like you said.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `this` in an erroneus way.

When you attach an **eventListener** like this:

```
$(element).on('click', function() {
   var id = $(this).parent().find('.user_id').text();
   alert(id)
}
```

the `this` will point to the **[target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)** of the event, and you code will work.

**BUT**, you are executing your function with `onclick=remove()`, so it's a **normal function call**, and in this case `this` will be the **global object** (the `window object` as we're in a browser).

You can add a `console.log(this)` to your function clearly see that.